# How to update the lead using php

Tags: soap-api, integration, php

Hi I have create the lead by using the following code but I dont know how to update the lead by using php.

My Code:

```
  //Describing the Leads object and printing the array
     $describe = $connection->describeSObjects(array('Lead'));
     print_r($describe);

     //Create New Lead
     $leadFirstName = $_POST['first_name'];
     $leadLastName = $_POST['last_name'];
     $leadCompany = "Testing";
     $leadEmail = $_POST['email'];
     $leadCountry = $_POST['country'];



     //Creating the Lead Object
     $lead = new stdClass;
     $lead->type = 'Lead';
     $lead->fields = array(
          'FirstName' => $leadFirstName,
          'LastName' => $leadLastName,
          'Company' => $leadCompany,
          'Email' => $leadEmail,
          'Country' => $leadCountry
     );

   //Submitting the Lead to Salesforce
     $result = $connection->create(array($lead), 'Lead');


   $sObject2 = new stdClass;
     $sObject2->type = 'Lead';
     $sObject2->fields = array(
          'FirstName' => 'Mary',
          'LastName' => 'Smith',
          'Company' => '510-486-9969',
          'Email' => '1rr@gmail.com'

     );




     $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->update(array($lead, $sObject2), 'Lead');

$ids = array();
foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
    print_r($createResult);
    array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
}

 }
```

How to get the id and update the fields. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to so the update immediately after create (after SF hands you back the ID)?  Or are you trying to locate a lead and THEN update it?

Comment: Yes, I want to when click the second button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $result object is an array of elements that describe if each lead was successfully inserted or not, as well as its ID value. You can use that ID value to update the lead in subsequent calls.

**Update** Taken from the [Samples](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_%28Enterprise%29) page:

```
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject, $sObject2), 'Contact');

$ids = array();
foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
    print_r($createResult);
    array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
}
```

Basically, you get an array() back, where each element has a value for `success` (boolean, true or false), and a `id` value (if success is true).

** Update 2 **

```
$sObject2->fields = array(
      'FirstName' => 'Mary',
      'LastName' => 'Smith',
      'Company' => '510-486-9969',
      'Email' => '1rr@gmail.com',
      'id' => $createResult[0]->id
 );
```

Comment: My question is how to get the ID value?

Comment: @disco See code...

Comment: Hi sfdcfox..I am fresher to php so please look at follwoing comment and provide the solution.
 I have updated your code but the field values not updated.
I would like to update sObject2 values to $lead .

Comment: `$result[0]->id` contains the newly created lead ID.

Comment: See my updated answer, then.

Comment: Yeah thanks.. I tried its working fine.. can you share you skype id? you are genius :)